# How do I display a different view based on membership role?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

I am brand new to MVC, and i'm jumping in head first.  I am creating a time and attendance application.  I want the user to simply log in and see the user interface for clocking in.  However, for salaried employees I want to provide a different interface.  My thought on this is to simply offer two views, but am unsure of the "customary" method of doing this.

For now i'm using the AccountController to handle authentication, and using standard Authorization attributes.

Should I simply have my home controller's index action check the role and return a different view?  Or should I somehow route users to different actions based on their membership role?

Comment: I think a lot would depend on if your alternate views have the same view model. Is this the case?

Comment: No, they would basically be totally different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to setup Roles and then use code like this in your views:

```
<%  
    if (User.IsInRole("AdminRole") 
        Html.RenderPartial("AdminView");  
    else if (User.IsInRole("SalariedRole") 
        Html.RenderPartial("SalaryView");  
%>
```

You can also do it with a filter:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/03/12/asp-net-mvc-framework-2-interception-and-creating-a-role-action-filter.aspx

Comment: Yes, this was my first thought, using partial rendering.  But it seemed like this would violate the SRP, using tow entirely different functions from the same controller action.

Comment: You can return two separate views if you want. Depends on how you want to organize your site.

Comment: If you like the answer, please mark the question complete by clicking on the checkmark.